# Pausing process after attaching to it in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Using `Debug -> Attach to Process by PID or Name...` in Xcode 8, I am able to wait for a program to launch before attaching lldb to it, akin to `process attach --name FOO --waitfor` in the command line.

Just like when launching a program, the command line suspends the program when it launches, dropping it somewhere in either `macho` or `dyld`. From there, I can set breakpoints and then continue (or basically start) the program and start my debugging.

Xcode however, successfully attaches to the program *but immediately continues execution*. Due to this, I cannot set breakpoints in early parts of startup logic.

Is there any way to either add breakpoints before attaching, or to prevent Xcode from automatically resuming the process?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an option to Xcode not to auto-continue after attach.  There are a couple of ways to get your breakpoints inserted, however.

If the process you are attaching to is one that you've built with an Xcode project, then you can edit the Run Scheme of that project, and in the `Info` tab set `Launch` to `Wait for Executable to launch` then hit `Run`.  That tells Xcode that the thing you are attaching to gets its breakpoints from this project, and will set them before continuing.  Then just set file & line or symbolic breakpoints in Xcode, and your on your way.

If you can't do that, then you can use the fact that breakpoints set in the ~/.lldbinit file get copied to all the new targets that lldb debugs.  That's another way to force some breakpoints into an Xcode debugging session.  So just set your breakpoints there, and they should get picked up on attach.